# Não listar dados duplicados

Tags: mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, `videos` e `exercicios`, onde eu gostaria que não fossem listados os dados que estão nas duas, ou seja, se a chave estrangeira está na outra tabela, o dado não deve ser mostrado na consulta para evitar de ser inserido novamente.

As tabelas:

```
videos(
  id_video,
  titulo_video,
  src_video,
  descricao_exercicio,
  id_professor_video,
  id_categoria_video,
  data_upload
)

exercicios(
  id_exercicio,
  id_treino_exercicio,
  id_aluno_exercicio,
  dia_exercicio
)
```

Tentei fazer como a *query* abaixo mas não deu certo, ele continua mostrando os `videos` que já foram cadastrados:

```sql
SELECT
  exercicios.*,
  videos.*
FROM (
  exercicios INNER JOIN videos
    ON exercicios.id_treino_exercicio = videos.id_video
)
WHERE 
  id_professor_video = 1
  AND id_categoria_video = 1
  AND dia_exercicio != 1
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada em outer join, resolve seu problema?

Comment: ou <not exists>

Comment: Sem saber a estrutura das suas tabelas, os dados que estão nela e um exemplo de resultado desejado com base nesses dados é impossível te ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

esse código funcionou do jeito que eu queria, acho que o join n estava dando certo pois n tinha nenhum campo null, mesmo assim obrigado a todos pela atenção.

```
SELECT * FROM videos v WHERE v.id_video NOT IN (SELECT id_treino_exercicio FROM exercicios) AND id_professor_video = 1 AND id_categoria_video = 1
```